# displaying output from two spinner

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a simple app on android studio which will allow me to pick two teams (from spinners) and then print out their final score or did not play.

I have been able to get the entire thing set up and working, however I can not get the scores to show in the textView. It always just says teams did not play

```
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1, adapter2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.list1,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
            spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    TextView spinner1Text = (TextView) view;

                }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.list2,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView spinner1Text = (TextView) view;

            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
       final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Show);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             button.refreshDrawableState();
            }
        });

        TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Score);

        if (spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Patriots")&& spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Seahawks")) {
            score.setText("Patriots 21, Seahawks 14" + "\n" + "Q1 Patroits 3 Seahawks 0" + "\n" + "Q2 Patroits 3 Seahawks 14" + "\n" + "Q3 Patroits 14 Seahawks 14" + "\n" + "Q4 Patroits 21 Seahawks 14");}

       else if (spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Falcons")&& spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Raiders")){
            score.setText("Falcons 3, Raiders 18" + "\n" + "Q1 Falcons 0 Raider 0" + "\n" + "Q2 Falcons 0 Raider 13" + "\n" + "Q3 Falcons 0 Raider 15" + "\n" + "Q4 Falcons 0 Raider 18");}

        else if (spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Eagles")&& spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Cowboys")){
            score.setText("Eagles 42, Cowboys 38" + "\n" + "Q1 Eagles 3 Cowboys 21" + "\n" + "Q2 Eagles 21 Cowboys 29" + "\n" + "Q3 Eagles 28 Cowboys 35" + "\n" + "Q4 Eagles 42 Cowboys 38");}

        else if (spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Bears")&& spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Redskins")){
            score.setText("Bears 20, Redskins 0" + "\n" + "Q1 Bears 3 Redskins 0" + "\n" + "Q2 Bears 3 Redskins 0" + "\n" + "Q3 Bears 17 Redskins 0" + "\n" + "Q4 Bears 20 Redskins 0");}

        else score.setText("Those two teams did not play each other");




        }
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">NFL Scorer Application</string>
    <string name="first_team">Please select the first team</string>
    <string name="second_team">Please select the second team</string>
    <string-array name="list1">

        <item></item>
        <item>Patriots</item>
        <item>Falcons</item>
        <item>Eagles</item>
        <item>Bears</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="list2">
        <item></item>
        <item>Seahawks</item>
        <item>Raiders</item>
        <item>Cowboys</item>
        <item>Redskins</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: move your `if-else` logic inside some listener , preferably second spinner listener

Comment: Thank you so much Pavneet Singh. That is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Pavneet Singh, I just needed to move the if-else into the listener